# Make one filter override the other with a name filter angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of data which I display using ng-repeat in AngularJS. The displayed data is filtered and then paginated based on user inputs, with the filter referring to a function in the controller.

Now what I want to do is to over-ride the current filter criteria if a user inputs text into a search field and only filter based on the inputted text. I.e. if a user inputs text then the other filters no longer apply and instead use the text filter. I feel like the way I have set it up it would be something around creating an if function in the controller's filter function and then re-creating the angular filter by text javascript. However, I am not sure how to do that and even if it is the right way.

Below is a snippet of the code which hopefully gives a good outline of the current state and what I am trying to achieve.

**TEXT SEARCH HTML**

```
<input         
ng-model="searchData.query"
type="text" 
name="productname"
id="productname"
class="form-control productname-answer">
```

**FILTER HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in (productsFilterd = (productData | filter: {productfilter:true} | orderBy:'relevance':true)).slice(((productData.currentPage-1)*productData.itemsPerPage), ((productData.currentPage)*productData.itemsPerPage))">
...
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
    $scope.getProductfilter = function() {
for (i = 0; i < $scope.productprofiles.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.productprofiles[i].reqlanguagecompara === 1 && $scope.productprofiles[i].reqservicecompara === 1) {
        $scope.productprofiles[i].productfilter = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.productprofiles[i].productfilter = false;
    };
    };
};
```

Comment: This is a _lot_ of stuff to be doing in the template.  I would make that whole ngRepeat a single function in the controller and instead iterate over the results of that function.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That can be done for sure, but would that help solve the initial issue of having two filters with one overriding the other in certain scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Please check a simplified working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c85gq14k/6/.

Try to wrap the logic into two filters function, one for default and one for customized:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('FilterCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.defaultFilter = function (n) {
        return n > 5;
    };
    $scope.inputFilter = function (n) {
        if ($scope.number) {
            return n > $scope.number;
        }
        return $scope.defaultFilter(n);
    };
}]);
```

The HTML is like:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
    <div ng-controller="FilterCtrl" id="play-ground">
        <input type="text" ng-model="number">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="i in ([1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34] | filter:inputFilter )" ng-bind="i"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever you enter a number, the default filter `n>5` is not applied.